# MATLAB HDF5 to Dask Dataframe Not Supported Yet?

Tags: pandas, matlab, dataframe, hdf5, dask

I am pulling a dataset out of a MATLAB mat file which is of HDF5 format as shown below:

```
matfile = 'C:\\....\\dataStuff.mat'
f = h5py.File(matfile, 'r')
data = f['/' + stuff + '/data/'].value
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # How do I create a Dask DF instead from data?
```

How do I do the same thing but instead of using Pandas, I create a Dask Dataframe?

The below function gives me an error:

```
  ddf = dd.read_hdf(matfile, 'key')
```

> the HDF5 class `H5T_COMPOUND` is not supported yet

I could attempt to just convert the Pandas DF into a Dask DF as shown below, but I would like to skip this step that takes another 2 minutes, but pulling the HDF5 data directly into a Dask Dataframe like I did with the Pandas.

```
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3) # What I don't want to do
```

Comment: Are you aware of [read_hdf](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_hdf) ?

Comment: @mdurant  when running read_hdf against this .mat file I receive this error: "the HDF5 class ``H5T_COMPOUND`` is not supported yet"